# Problem with reading Booleans with Thymeleaf (Java)

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I got problem with reading Boolean values from object with Thymeleaf. This is what it looks like in the code:

```
                    <tr th:each="item : ${individualTransactions}">
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemName}"> </span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemDescription}"> </span></td>
                        <td><span th:text="${item.itemCost}"> </span></td>
                        <td>
                            <div th:switch="${item.isUsed}">
                                <p th:case="true"> USED </p>
                                <p th:case="false"> USE </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

and this is the message: EL1008E: Property or field 'isUsed' cannot be found on object of type 'xxx.entity.Transaction' - maybe not public or not valid?

I don't know if the problem is in my syntax or in accessing the property. There is no problem with access to other properties.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaBeans specification §8.3.2](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf#page=55):

> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> ```
> public boolean is<PropertyName>();
> ```

Your property name is `used`, not `isUsed`.

Comment: I changed getter and setter names - default names were getUsed and setUsed, I changed them to getIsUsed and setIsUsed and it works now.

Comment: @krzysiekcr you should've changed the template to `${item.used}`.

Comment: I didn't understand you at first - of course you are right.